# How to store original iframe markup into database without html encoding

Tags: php, iframe, encoding, html-encode

I am new in PHP and I have wysihtml5 editor in my form and when I am adding iframe code in editor to store value into database iframe code encoded like:

```
&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ycHXRWRKrdA?rel=0&quot;">http://www.youtube.com/embed/ycHXRWRKrdA?rel=0"</a>; frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;<br>
```

I want to store iframe code like below

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ycHXRWRKrdA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which wysiwyg editor is it? You should not add HTML code in WYSIWYG mode in it. Almost all wysiwyg editors have "Source" button where you can edit the HTML itself, and it DOES save a normal HTML, not the &tags;

Comment: @OlegDubas I am using bootstrap wysiwyg editor.

Comment: @300988 Bootstrap doesn't have an official WYSIWYG editor, so it'd be good if you could link the specific one.

Answer (score -1):

you should apply http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php to your string when is saved or when is displayed

Comment: That'll decode *everything*, which is unlikely to be desired.